# Does a django migration failure modify the databse?

Tags: django, database-migration

I need to know if getting an error while running python manage.py migrate means my database will remain in the same state it was before running the migrate command.

I'm trying to implement migrations as part of a CI system and it would be good to know if I need to do some kind of rollback if the migrations fails.

Comment: Depends on the DB you are using, for instance, MySQL does modify even if a migration fails. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#mysql

Answer (score 4):

As [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#backend-support) explains, it depends on the database.

PostgreSQL can use transactions for schema alteration operations, so Django does so, and rolls back in case of failure. But MySQL does not support this.